# How to exclude other domain from server url?

Tags: linux, .htaccess, codeigniter, amazon-ec2, server

I have two projects in aws linux server like:

```
/var/www/html/codeigniter-project/
/var/www/html/other-project/
```

And the url of codeigniter project is:

```
http://ip/
```

If i open other-project like `http://ip/other-project` then it display `Internal Server Error`.
So, how i exclude this folder from url or how to open other project like `http://ip/other-project`?

Answer (score 0):

You are using correct way. I think the other-project have some issue in code. Do one thing copy codeigniter-project in same and rename it like codeigniter-project2 then try to run it with http://ip/codeigniter-project2

Comment: No other project is not in any framework, code is core php, If i use codeigniter like `http://ip/codeigniter-project/` then other project is working. I changed `http://ip/codeigniter-project` to `http://ip/` in httpd.conf ( Changed DocumentRoot ).
Maybe this problem is generated by htaccess.

Comment: In these situations what I do is to set up a virutal server for each project so i have in apache `http://ip/project1` and `http://ip/project2` each one with his own configuration

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Tk42421,  set up virtual servers for each project.
`http://ip/project1` : point document root to one folder,
`http://ip/project2` : point document root to another folder

Here is a guide on  how to do so: [virtual servers digitalocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-apache-web-server-on-centos-7)